# how to feed raw audio as input to generative adversarial network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, adversarial-machines

I have followed tutorials to generate image using generative adversarial network but i have no idea on how to feed audio as input to network .Do i need to do some transformation on the audio data or can give directly to the network.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, can you post an example of the input?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have generated digits using GAN. I want to classify audio using GAN. Input can be any form either open data set or can be created manually.